# Open gallery to a video without autoplay

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery

I'm trying to open a video in gallery view without playing it. Like the following, how can I do that:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it does not appear as though the stock Gallery app supports opening a video via Intent and not immediately playing the video.

As per the source for the Gallery's [MovieActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/master/src/com/android/gallery3d/app/MovieActivity.java) and [MoviePlayer](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/master/src/com/android/gallery3d/app/MoviePlayer.java), the app will immediately start playing videos when the MovieActivity finishes loading the video.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted the answer. Do you know if I could fork the view (the one in the screenshot, is it MovieActivity ?) and use it.

Comment: I don't see why not! The source is licensed under the Apache License. If you find it's not working well for you, there are also other options such a using a [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html)